# Scraping many pages from one domain

Tags: python-3.x, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

Hi Can you advise a code which will be scraping a web site page by page?

e.g. from the web site: https://bookshop.org/categories/m/fantasy?page=2

If I want to search all pages from https://bookshop.org/categories/m/fantasy?page=2 till https://bookshop.org/categories/m/fantasy?page=100

For now I have this:

```
import requests 
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as soup 
from requests import get

url="https://bookshop.org/categories/m/fantasy?page=2"

r = requests.get(url, proxies={'http':'82.119.170.106'})

page = soup(r.content, "html.parser")

contents=page.findAll("div", class_="booklist")


for content in contents:
    title_text=content.h2.text
    print(title_text)
```

And the purpose is to get all titles from pages 2-100

Answer (score 0):

```py
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from concurrent.futures.thread import ThreadPoolExecutor


def main(page):
    print(f"Extracting Page# {page}")
    r = requests.get(
        "https://bookshop.org/categories/m/fantasy?page={}".format(page))
    soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, 'html.parser')
    target = [item.h2.get_text(strip=True)
              for item in soup.select("div.booklist-book")]
    return target


with ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=100) as executor:
    futures = executor.map(main, range(2, 101))
    final = []
    for future in futures:
        final.extend(future)

print(final)
```

Full Output: [here](https://pastebin.com/raw/wkSQa3FY)